# Warning detected during compilation

Tags: warnings

When compiling my document, I have several warnings which are detected but I do not understand them all

my preamble :

```
  \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picinpar}

\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\alph{subsubsection}}
```

- LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size <6.49994> not available
  (Font)              size <6> substituted on input line 908.

  \item '{A} l'aide du 1\ier{} volume équivalent $V_{eq1}$, calculer la concentration en acide chlorhydrique.
- LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
  (Font)              up to 0.49994pt have occurred.

Can you help me to understand them (and solve them).

Thanks

Comment: add `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before \documentclass.

Comment: Nice : thanks @UlrikeFischer

Comment: The warning means that you tried to access a font at a given size (here 6.49994pt), but the used font isn't scalable and the requested size wasn't available (hence it was substituted with the next available size, being 6pt). What `fix-cm` does is to provide a scalable Computer Modern font (hence @UlrikeFischer's advice to load it).